# Changing HTML using javascript without using selectors

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, responsive-design, ssi

Ok - first of all I know this isn't ideal - however we have inherited a problem and some badly thought out SSI html.

So some background: We have implemented a responsive site which has to include some SSI code from the client for global top nav and footer - so far so good. However the SSI needs to change from DESKTOP to MOBILE as the site is resized/loaded on a mobile device. We do all this client side at the moment. We have a trigger at break points to alter the dom to do all the responsive stuff.

A similar example is here http://www.conrandesigngroup.com. (Resize the browser to see what happens.)

Normally we would load the SSI into holding pages and AJAX the code in to the appropriate place using some kind of selector.

The problem: The SSI is not fully formed HTML, it looks something like this:

```
<!-- desktop ssi -->
</head>
<body>
Whole bunch of desktop html...
<div class="content">
```

Then the SSI we have for the mobile site is:

```
<!-- mobile ssi -->
<script>some script...</script>
</head>
<body>
Whole bunch of mobile html...
<div class="content">
```

So you will notice there is a closing`</head>` and an opening `<body>` and at the end there is an opening `<div>`. So there is no way we can select this and replace using the DOM. We were thinking of using comments either side of the code and using a javascript regex to replace the code. Im not sure if this would actually update the browser.

So in desktop mode the whole page will look like this:

```
<html>
<title>my page</title>
<head>
...all the head stuff
<!-- START of ssi -->
<!-- desktop ssi -->
</head>
<body>
Whole bunch of desktop html...
<div class="content">
<!-- END of SSI -->
...all the page HTML
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So thats fine - the HTML is all put together serverside and we can open and close the tags correctly. The problem is how would we change the HTML INSIDE the comments using client side code `<!- START of ssi -->...<!-- END of SSI -->`

In the end its not really a SSI question - rather a way to change a bit of HTML which is not wrapped up nicely in an element.

Anyone come across this issue before or have any suggestions?

Comment: is the 2nd `</head>` there on purpose?

Comment: Yes - the 2 bits of code are from 2 different server side includes. We have no control over these files. The closing head is part of the problem.

Comment: Why are the responsive elements being driven from server side?  Are media queries being used?  Maybe I am having a hard time understanding the problem?

Comment: Its a legacy problem. The SSI files are something we have to include - they are global navigation for the corporate site. The responsive elements are not being driven server side its all static HTML (with SSI) with the responsive stuff done client side.

Comment: So we have to supply static HTML - with SSI. BUT the html in the SSI has to change for mobile and desktop. We cant change the SSI - they are basically static. So we need to be able to effectively load in a different SSI for different front end modes.

Comment: (I know SSI is done server side btw, however all our logic needs to be done client side)

Answer (score 0):

The common denominator is this:

- The `body` element contains the content
- Both the mobile and desktop content start with the first child of the body

The code to empty the first element would be the same for both versions:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].firstChild.innerHTML = "";
```

Wrap the code in a `pre` element to make it easy to modify.

**References**

- [W3C DOM4](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/)